# MockitoHint 1. Unused... -> at

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

After updated to Spring Boot 2.6.x, I have NullPointerException. While running the Test case in this line. `when(packageControl.tryPackage(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), anyList())).thenReturn("XXXXXX");`

I have this below error `20:13:55.654 [main] INFO XXXXXXXXX - Start Read an Document List. [MockitoHint] XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (see javadoc for MockitoHint): [MockitoHint] 1. Unused... -> at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (ListActivityTest.java:298) [MockitoHint]  ...args ok? -> at xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(ListActivity.java:213)`